# Why is stack for pair-nesting analysis often empty?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

The following is my code where I try to check for the balanced parenthesis.

```
def is_matched(expression):
    opening = tuple('({[');
    closing = tuple(')}]');
    mapping = dict(zip(opening,closing));
    queue = [];

    for letter in expression : 
        if letter in opening : 
            queue.append(mapping[letter]);
        elif letter in closing : 
            if (not queue) or (letter != queue.pop()) :
                return False;
    return not queue;

ip = input();
if is_matched(ip):
    print ("Valid");
else:
    print("Invalid");
```

My question is why the `queue` list is getting to `[]` state for every letter in the input parameter in the for loop?
Should it not append every dictionary mapping in the loop?

Comment: Python doesn't end lines with semicolons. Just a simple return is all you need.

Comment: @chrisaycock Python *can* end lines with semicolons?

Comment: @JohnLaw It can, but doesn't need to. It's certainly not idiomatic in the OP's context.

Comment: I don't understand the question.. your code seems to work for me

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is ?  what od you mean by the queue list is getting to `empty list` state for every letter ? It's only appending to queue when it finds a character in `opening`

Comment: @ItsMeGokul lists are not mutable that way? `.pop()` immediately removes the last element and returns it? Maybe that? Also **important**: give examples of test cases, inputs and outputs.

Comment: Another note, not so sure of this but I'll say it anyways. Using `.append()` (add at end) and `.pop()` (take from end) makes it resemble more a **stack** instead of a **queue**?

Comment: @JohnLaw Actually, I’m pretty sure the OP _is_ after a stack, and it’s the variable name that’s wrong, not the operations.

Comment: @abarnert Ah, I see... somewhat misleading. :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not "append every dictionary mapping".
It only appends anything for letters found in `opening`.
What gets appended is the counterpart from `closing`.
It will quite often return the queue to `[]`, because it does also a lot of `pop()`,
which reomves a letter.
The `pop()` occurs when the current letter from input matches the last appended letter,
i.e. when a recently opened pair gets closed.
So for example, the queue is `[]` at these positions for the following input:

```
vvv     vvv     vvv     vvv         vvvvv
abc(xxxx)fg[....]hi{llll}gh(--[ff]++)gggg
```

Note, as also mentioned in the comments, `queue` behaves more like a stack here, and rightly so.